# One-to-many relationship between applicationuser and custom entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I get an error that says "ApplicationUser_Cars_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Cars_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Cars'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
"
when I try to update my database, here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string ProfilePicture { get;set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cars")]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}


public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the fluent api requirement I have... It should be optional for users to register a car

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasOptional(x => x.Cars);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, first of all I had to make the foreign key in the application user table  nullable and add a .withMany() method to the fluentAPI like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string ProfilePicture { get;set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cars")]
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

and this:
        modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasOptional(x => x.Cars).withMany();

Comment: Consider accepting your answer by pressing the checkbox near your answer.